# AppIdentityService::getApplicationId return "None"

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, dev-appserver

I am trying to setup local development on my computer and have had some success.  I can start the local server with dev_appserver.py and can access my local MySQL server through my php app.

I'm a noob with gcp, but have many years of experience.

When I try to execute the following code it returns "None":

```php
$applicationID = AppIdentityService::getApplicationId();
```

Where do I set the Application ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Application ID is generated and assigned by the App Engine runtime environment. It will be `null` or `None` when run locally before the app is deployed to App Engine.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  This does raise the bigger issue of how do I debug my app locally.  I thought getting the Application ID would be trivial, but apparently it is not when running locally.

Before I tried this,  I tried to create a bucket, but got the following error:


make_call(): Remote implementation for app_identity_service.GetAccessToken failed in ...

Is this also something that I cannot do on my local machine?

Comment: I think you may get better help if you post that question separately. In short, you can operate on buckets locally as long as you have the right credentials set up.

Answer (score 0):

There is not way you can set your Application ID by yourself. There is also no method for that. The Application ID is set by App Engine after your deployment.

[Here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php/refdocs/classes/google.appengine.api.app_identity.AppIdentityService) there is a list of all the methods of the AppIdentityService